# Error when user-managed worker service account and dataflow-job are in different projects

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Error when running dataflow when user managed worker service account and dataflow job are in different projects

The error I'm getting is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "google.dataflow.v1beta3.JobsV1Beta3.ListJobs",
          "service": "dataflow.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The permission for the user-managed worker service account inside the Dataflow Code are:
Dataflow Admin
Dataflow Worker
Service Account User
Storage Admin

No error when user-managed worker service account and dataflow-job are in the same project.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your issue, the service account of the project A needs to have the permissions to the project B (in the `IAM` of project B, add the permissions for service account given by the project A).

You also need to pass the following program argument to the `Dataflow` job :

For `Beam` `Python` :

```
--service_account_email

—-service_account_email=my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

For `Beam` `Java` :

```
--serviceAccount

—-serviceAccount=my-service-account-name@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  
However, specifying --project=projectB in the program argument resulted in the same error.  
Can't it be executed in projectB?

Comment: Yes you have to execute it in the project B

Comment: Thanks for the input.Is it because the credential information of the service account specified in the program argument is searched from the project specified in the program argument?

Comment: Yes, you run your Dataflow job from the project B. The service account is in the project A. The service account of the project A needs to have the permissions to the project B.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting does not match your question.

The error you are getting is because the request does not have any Authentication headers. There is no google ServiceAccount or user associated to the request, therefore it can not proceed. It is an anonymous request for GCP.

Review where you are initiating the request and why it does not have the authentication information: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

When the user is identified but it does not have permission to do the action you will receive an unauthorized error message.